# In postfix can I mention sender access map in client restriction?

Tags: email, postfix, email-server, milter, e-mailrelay

It's a question out of curiosity rather than necessity. What should happen say I place sender access map inside  `smtpd_client_restrictions` and also place client access map in `smtpd_sender_restrictions` and set delay_reject to no. My understanding is that:

1. When the postfix will try to match the hash maps on client connect it should fail as there is sender address present at the time of matching (so I guess it'll pass to next restriction with DUNNO).
2. But this will be applied before any sender_restriction once sender address is present.
3. Sender restriction will be ignored till Mail From command is sent and after that the client white list (access map) will get evaluated.
4. In the meanwhile all the commands will still go to smtpd milters so they can block emails even before smtpd sender_restriction.

Please see if and where I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Yup, those nonsensical with `smtpd_delay_reject=no` are ignored, as per [`postconf(5)`](https://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtpd_client_restrictions):

> When helo, sender or recipient restrictions are listed under
> smtpd_client_restrictions, they have effect only with
> "smtpd_delay_reject = yes", so that $smtpd_client_restrictions is
> evaluated at the time of the RCPT TO command.

Which is okay if you duplicate those lookups elsewhere, and a really sweet [footgun](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/footgun) otherwise.

Comment: I have used to put almost everything in `smtpd_recipient_restrictions` to be evaluated after `RCPT TO`, but `smtpd_delay_reject` already does it for me and is turned on by default! Didn't think I would learn something new on Postfix. Thanks!

Comment: @EsaJokinen I usually write `man section name` instead of the `name(section)` because I love running shell commands copied right off the internet without even having to care about shell escapes. Is there any portability issue about the other 2 spellings, or did you merely edit it to match the conventional reference style?

Comment: I just think this looks better on this format, and it is already a hyperlink to the manpage, although sometimes you would have to check whether you have different version / flavour. That's why I don't prefer a certain site publishing manpages, but try to find one closest to the OPs environment, if that information is available in the question. (But that was also to avoid the minimum modification limit.)